# what is ***91 / ***93 in python

Tags: python, syntax

I see some codes that my friend shared, they have something like:

```
mylist = open(sys.argv***91;1***93;, "r").read() 
re.findall('***91;\.\w***93;+@***91;a-zA-Z_***93;+?\.***91;a-zA-Z***93;{2,3}', database)
```

I did some searches but couldn't come up with the good anwser. What do the ***91 or 93 mean?

**Answers from Martijn:**
Thanks the code is corrupted. I transferred the code from the openSUSE that the my friends uploaded to my ubuntu and somehow the character [, ] are replaced by ***91 and ***93.

Comment: They are gibberish. Invalid syntax. Your files look corrupted.

Comment: Where did you get that code? My guess is that it's bad encoding for `[` and `]`

Comment: They look like the ASCII codes for bracket characters.  Something messed up your files.

Comment: isn't it obfuscation? `***91;` = `[`, `***93;` = `]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you are looking at has been corrupted. That's **not** valid Python code.

Only by replacing all `***91;` and `***93;` references with `[` and `]` does it become anything runnable:

```
mylist = open(sys.argv[1], "r").read() 
re.findall('[\.\w]+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}', database)
```

`91` and `93` happen to be the decimal ASCII codepoints for `[` and `]` respectively; something didn't transfer the code quite correctly.

Comment: Thank it worked, i transferred it from another unix dix and somehow it messed up some characters.